# Yahoo Finance API - GET quotes returns "Invalid Cookie"

Tags: http, http-headers, yahoo-finance, yahoo-api

For the past few years, I've been using the following link to fetch a full current quote for the symbols in the query:

https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/v7/finance/quote?symbols=AAPL

All of a sudden, as of about 5 hours ago, I'm now getting the error response 'Unauthorised - Invalid Cookie' on every single device I call it from. Sometimes, I get the error response 'Unauthorised - Invalid Crumb'.

The historic data fetching still works fine:

(https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/v8/finance/chart/AAPL?metrics=high?&interval=1d&range=5d).

Is anyone else having this issue and/or knows how I can fix it??? Or have Yahoo discontinued this endpoint without telling anyone??

Comment: I am having the same problem with the quotes query (also since yesterday). Searching for tickers still works, though:
https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/v1/finance/search?q=AAPL

Comment: Even Alfian Losari's fantastic StocksApp tutorial has the same problem:
https://github.com/alfianlosari/stocksapptutorial

Comment: It seems the original link is working again.. Can anyone confirm this too?

Comment: You need to add the `crumb` get parameter for it to work. You can get a crumb value when browsing yahoo finance. Look for access to `https://query2.finance.yahoo.com/v1/test/getcrumb` and copy the crumb value

Comment: Full explanation here https://github.com/scheb/yahoo-finance-api/issues/44

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I had the same issue today. Change the "v7" to "v6" in the URL in your GET request. It will then work, at least for now. Because the Yahoo Finance API hasn't been officially supported since 2017, we do what we can with it.

Comment: I've only been trying versions greater than v7! Thank you so much, absolute hero

Comment: v6 is still working, I had to also include the following header though: "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:109.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/112.0"

Comment: I ran into the same issue +/- the same date. To solve the problem, I tried the crumb and cookie stuff but failed to retrieve the cookie via VBA (crumb was fine). I finally found the solution mentioned by switching to v6. However... since 2 days I get as return: {"finance":{"result":null,"error":{"code":"Not Found","description":"HTTP 404 Not Found"}}}.

Any other ideas how to get the data retrieval working again? Or (in the light of the post below), does anyone know where to find a detailed manual for using the Google Finance API instead (as I actually don't care where the data comes from)?

Comment: Oof... going from `v7` to `v6` worked for a month or so, for me. Now neither works. v7 returns *"Invalid Crumb"* and v6 returns *"Not found"*.

Comment: v10 used to work until about last month. Not any longer

Comment: The v6 API returns not found and is no longer supported.

Answer (score 9):

that might explain why it isn't working anymore!

[image]

Comment: Thank you for this, where and when did you see this message? The API has certainly stopped working completely now for a couple of days.

Comment: I have found and tested a library yesterday that is working: https://github.com/karlwancl/YahooFinanceApi/tree/14b6c587d94ebe551f11f44c6b954d64285b831c. Be sure to use the pull request 55 which contains the fix.

Comment: Yes, what is the source of the API Feedback message?

Answer (score 8):

I came across the same problem and switched to using the `https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/v8/finance/chart/{ticker}` endpoint which seems to work. The response format is slightly different but seems to contain similar information.

E.g. to get the current price:

Old endpoint:
`quoteResponse.result[0].regularMarketPrice`

New endpoint:
`chart.result[0].meta.regularMarketPrice`

Comment: Confirmed this endpoint is working. Doesn't seem to return as much metadata but at least you get currency and the exchange.

Answer (score 4):

If you try to go to a quote api endpoint such as:
https://query2.finance.yahoo.com/v7/finance/quote?symbols=AAL

You end up getting this:
{"finance":{"result":null,"error":{"code":"Unauthorized","description":"Invalid Crumb. For Developers - [https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSeyb7xMtZFjoNYI7XG1rjlhUopKAxdLAfSRcaPxg9p-9ii-_g/viewform?fbzx=-7189957683680596558"}}}](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSeyb7xMtZFjoNYI7XG1rjlhUopKAxdLAfSRcaPxg9p-9ii-_g/viewform?fbzx=-7189957683680596558%22%7D%7D%7D) (i replaced the bitly link for posting)

[image: Yahoo Finance | API Feedback]

Where they explain how they've disabled access to quote data.

The v6 endpoint was killed off entirely.

Answer (score 3):

An alternative I found on https://cryptocointracker.com/yahoo-finance/yahoo-finance-api#26cc3f3f62db4567857919c2653fab33 is to use [https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/v7/finance/options/{symbol}](https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/v7/finance/options/%7Bsymbol%7D)
It has `quote` value-pair containing:

```json
{
   "quote":{
      "language":"en-US",
      "region":"US",
      "quoteType":"EQUITY",
      "typeDisp":"Equity",
      "quoteSourceName":"Delayed Quote",
      "triggerable":true,
      "customPriceAlertConfidence":"HIGH",
      "exchange":"NMS",
      "currency":"USD",
      "earningsTimestamp":1691092800,
      "earningsTimestampStart":1691092800,
      "earningsTimestampEnd":1691092800,
      "trailingAnnualDividendRate":0.92,
      "trailingPE":32.131535,
      "dividendRate":0.96,
      "trailingAnnualDividendYield":0.004847974,
      "dividendYield":0.51,
      "epsTrailingTwelveMonths":5.93,
      "epsForward":6.58,
      "epsCurrentYear":5.98,
      "priceEpsCurrentYear":31.862875,
      "sharesOutstanding":15728700416,
      "bookValue":3.953,
      "fiftyDayAverage":180.4268,
      "fiftyDayAverageChange":10.11319,
      "fiftyDayAverageChangePercent":0.05605148,
      "twoHundredDayAverage":156.0571,
      "twoHundredDayAverageChange":34.482895,
      "marketCap":2996946599936,
      "twoHundredDayAverageChangePercent":0.22096333,
      "forwardPE":28.957447,
      "priceToBook":48.201363,
      "sourceInterval":15,
      "exchangeDataDelayedBy":0,
      "averageAnalystRating":"2.0 - Buy",
      "shortName":"Apple Inc.",
      "longName":"Apple Inc.",
      "messageBoardId":"finmb_24937",
      "exchangeTimezoneName":"America/New_York",
      "exchangeTimezoneShortName":"EDT",
      "gmtOffSetMilliseconds":-14400000,
      "market":"us_market",
      "esgPopulated":false,
      "marketState":"POSTPOST",
      "regularMarketChangePercent":0.40574852,
      "regularMarketPrice":190.54,
      "tradeable":false,
      "cryptoTradeable":false,
      "firstTradeDateMilliseconds":345479400000,
      "priceHint":2,
      "postMarketChangePercent":-0.11545396,
      "postMarketTime":1689292799,
      "postMarketPrice":190.32,
      "postMarketChange":-0.21998596,
      "regularMarketChange":0.769989,
      "regularMarketTime":1689278404,
      "regularMarketDayHigh":191.19,
      "regularMarketDayRange":"189.78 - 191.19",
      "regularMarketDayLow":189.78,
      "regularMarketVolume":38321242,
      "regularMarketPreviousClose":189.77,
      "bid":190.34,
      "ask":190.38,
      "bidSize":10,
      "askSize":10,
      "fullExchangeName":"NasdaqGS",
      "financialCurrency":"USD",
      "regularMarketOpen":190.5,
      "averageDailyVolume3Month":56677663,
      "averageDailyVolume10Day":51027070,
      "fiftyTwoWeekLowChange":66.369995,
      "fiftyTwoWeekLowChangePercent":0.5345091,
      "fiftyTwoWeekRange":"124.17 - 194.48",
      "fiftyTwoWeekHighChange":-3.9400024,
      "fiftyTwoWeekHighChangePercent":-0.020259166,
      "fiftyTwoWeekLow":124.17,
      "fiftyTwoWeekHigh":194.48,
      "fiftyTwoWeekChangePercent":26.882862,
      "dividendDate":1684368000,
      "displayName":"Apple",
      "symbol":"AAPL"
   }
}
```

Comment: You never know when the end-point is no longer working as I have experience on the two of their APIs.

Answer (score 2):

I just checked and v7 is now working again.

Comment: As of yesterday and today, v7 is failing again. But I just stumbled upon this post, and v6 works. Yeehaw!

Comment: according to a non-answer posted as ananswer, v7 and v6 are failing today.

Comment: Today (May 26, 2023 8am CEST), neither v6 nor v7 is working. v6 returns 404 not found, v7 returns "invalid cookie".

Comment: This one still works:

"https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/v11/finance/quoteSummary/" & sShare & "?modules=financialData"

but it retrieves a lot of data I am not at all interested in, and I can't query all symbols together.

Comment: I have found and tested a library yesterday that is working: github.com/karlwancl/YahooFinanceApi/tree/…. Be sure to use the pull request 55 which contains the fix.

Answer (score 2):

This is my working version that I am using it in a .Net 7 API project. I've solved the problem with the **cookie** and **crumb** by keeping them in cache and I have a sync/retry mechanism when the cache expires. This works well for 1 server instance but for scale situation it should be rethink. This is using **Yahoo V10** without problems. There is no requests limiter here but I advise you to use one. In my case I have something build in UI (not very efficient, but is good enough for my case).

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory;
using System.Net;

namespace WorkbenchAPI.Features.ServiceDelivery.StockMarket.SymbolsParsers
{
   public class YahooManager
   {
    private static readonly object yahooCredentialsLocker = new object();

    private const string STOCK_MARKET_URL_SUMMARY = "https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/v10/finance/quoteSummary/{0}?formatted=true&lang=en-US&region=US&modules=assetProfile%2CbalanceSheetHistory%2CbalanceSheetHistoryQuarterly%2CcalendarEvents%2CcashflowStatementHistory%2CcashflowStatementHistoryQuarterly%2CdefaultKeyStatistics%2Cearnings%2CearningsHistory%2CearningsTrend%2CesgScores%2CfinancialData%2CfundOwnership%2CincomeStatementHistory%2CincomeStatementHistoryQuarterly%2CindexTrend%2CindustryTrend%2CinsiderHolders%2CinsiderTransactions%2CinstitutionOwnership%2CmajorDirectHolders%2CmajorHoldersBreakdown%2CnetSharePurchaseActivity%2Cprice%2CrecommendationTrend%2CsecFilings%2CsectorTrend%2CsummaryDetail%2CsummaryProfile%2CupgradeDowngradeHistory%2Cpageviews%2Cquotetype&ssl=true";

    private const string YahooFcUrl = "https://fc.yahoo.com";
    private const string YahooGetCrumbUrl = "https://query2.finance.yahoo.com/v1/test/getcrumb";
    private const string CacheKeyCookieContainer = "YahooCookieContainer";
    private const string CacheKeyCrumb = "YahooCrumb";

    private readonly IHttpClientFactory _httpClientFactory;
    private readonly IMemoryCache _memCache;

    public YahooManager(IHttpClientFactory httpClientFactory, IMemoryCache memCache)
    {
        _httpClientFactory = httpClientFactory;
        _memCache = memCache;
    }


    public async Task<string> GetYahooSymbolSummay(string symbol)
    {
        return await WebRequestGet(string.Format(STOCK_MARKET_URL_SUMMARY, symbol));
    }

    public async Task<string> WebRequestGet(string url)
    {
        (CookieContainer cookie, string crumb) credentials = new(null, null);
        lock (yahooCredentialsLocker)
        {
            int tryCounter = 0;
            while ((credentials.crumb == null || credentials.cookie == null) && tryCounter < 10)
            {
                Task.Delay(1000 * tryCounter).Wait();
                credentials = GetYahooCookie().ConfigureAwait(false).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
                tryCounter++;
            }//while
        }//lock

        string sAgent = $"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/115.0.0.0 Safari/537.36";
        var httpRequestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, url + "&crumb=" + credentials.crumb)
        {
            Headers =
                        {
                            { "Cookie",  credentials.cookie.GetCookieHeader(new Uri(YahooFcUrl))},
                            { "User-Agent",sAgent }
                        }
        };
        var httpClient = _httpClientFactory.CreateClient();
        var webResponse = await httpClient.SendAsync(httpRequestMessage);
        //webResponse.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
        string responseContent = await webResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        return responseContent;
    }//WebRequestGet

    private async Task<(CookieContainer cookie, string crumb)> GetYahooCookie()
    {
        CookieContainer m_cookieContainer = null;
        string m_crumb = null;
        _memCache.TryGetValue(CacheKeyCookieContainer, out m_cookieContainer);
        _memCache.TryGetValue(CacheKeyCrumb, out m_crumb);

        if (m_cookieContainer == null || m_crumb == null)
        {               
            string sAgent = $"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/115.0.0.0 Safari/537.36";

            m_cookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
            var uri = new Uri(YahooFcUrl);
            var httpRequestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, YahooFcUrl)
            {
                Headers =
                        {
                            { "User-Agent", sAgent }
                        }
            };
            var httpClient = _httpClientFactory.CreateClient();
            var httpResponseMessage = await httpClient.SendAsync(httpRequestMessage);
            IEnumerable<string> cookies;
            httpResponseMessage.Headers.TryGetValues("Set-Cookie", out cookies);
            if (cookies == null)                                    
                return (null, null);
            
            foreach (var cookieValue in cookies)
                m_cookieContainer.SetCookies(uri, cookieValue);
            httpResponseMessage.Dispose();

            httpRequestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, YahooGetCrumbUrl)
            {
                Headers =
                        {
                            { "Cookie",  m_cookieContainer.GetCookieHeader(uri) },
                            { "User-Agent",sAgent}
                        }
            };
            httpClient = _httpClientFactory.CreateClient();
            var crumbResponse = await httpClient.SendAsync(httpRequestMessage);
            crumbResponse.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
            string responseContent = await crumbResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            m_crumb = responseContent.Trim('"');

            var cacheEntryOptions = new MemoryCacheEntryOptions()
                .SetSlidingExpiration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60*5))
                .SetAbsoluteExpiration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60*10))
                .SetPriority(CacheItemPriority.Normal);
            _memCache.Set(CacheKeyCookieContainer, m_cookieContainer, cacheEntryOptions);
            _memCache.Set(CacheKeyCrumb, m_crumb, cacheEntryOptions);
        }//endif
        return (m_cookieContainer, m_crumb);
    }//GetYahooCookie


  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The only option that I've found is to use a different service.  I have a paid subscription to Financial Modeling Plus (https://site.financialmodelingprep.com/developer/docs/pricing/)

They have a free tier that provides 250 quotes a day.  That might be adequate for some people that only want daily updates for their portfolio.

Comment: Great suggestion. I looked at their specs, seems better than the Yahoo. Also, in the long run, it is more sustainable to pay for the access

Comment: In my experience Yahoo has better data quality at least for European stocks.

Answer (score -1):

I suspect there are some rate limiting at work. If you are making too many calls too quickly, the endpoint will treat the caller as an automated program instead of a human users. I started getting a lot of `Unauthorized` after calling one of the endpoints a few thousand times. Tried again after a few minutes and the request went through.

Comment: This is not rate limiting related. The error is related to Yahoo Finance aiming to stop illegal API usage and requesting feedback on the intended API usage.