Yahoo Finance indicates symbol doesn't exist when it actually does exist
On a daily basis, I download a fixed set of 100 closing prices, using the tickers, from Yahoo!. They all work as expected 99% of the time. This is done using an HttpWebRequest to download a web page.
However, occasionally Yahoo! will return html that indicates that the symbol doesn't exist.
E.g. the returned HTML will contain something like: Symbols similar to 'XOM'

However, if that same URL is pasted into a browser, then the actual expected HTML is downloaded.
Sample URL: https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/XOM/history/?p=XOM&period1=1729839600&period2=1729925999
Code to download webpage:
HttpWebRequest wr = (HttpWebRequest) HttpWebRequest.Create(url);
wr.Proxy = null;
wr.UserAgent = userAgent; // copied from browser

String html = null;
var r = wr.GetResponse();
using (r) {
    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(r.GetResponseStream(), true)) {
        html = sr.ReadToEnd();
    }
}

Any ideas why Yahoo! sometimes doesn't recognize a symbol as existing?

I've seen something like this happen before when I hit the server with too many requests all at once. I learned to space them out. One request every three or five seconds. I don't know if that's the problem, but you might give it a try.

Why don't u try my approach. The API still works but u don't know it. Check my answer from here and give it a try. For me works great even today in my project: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76059562/yahoo-finance-api-get-quotes-returns-invalid-cookie/77013486#77013486
